# include different file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<div class="btn02 lang">EN</div>
<div class="btn02 lang">YU</div>
```

JS

```
$(".lang").click(function() {
     var lang = $(this).html();
     alert (lang);
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "params.php",
        data: {lang:lang}
    });
     window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```

params.php

```
if (isset($_POST["lang"]) && $_POST["lang"] == "EN") {
    $lang = "EN";
}
elseif (isset($_POST["lang"]) && $_POST["lang"] == "YU"){
    $lang = "YU";
}
else {
    $lang = "EN";
}
```

index.php

```
    include "params.php";
    if ($lang == "EN") {
    include "inc/modals.php";
    }
    else {
    include "inc/modals_yu.php";
    }
```

So, when I click on `.lang` button containing `YU` I expect to reload the page (it works) and include `modals_yu.php` instead of `modals.php`. This doesn't work. `modals.php` is allways included.

Comment: On page refresh your `$_POST` values are lost. You could use a `$_SESSION` variable so that it is still available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are making an AJAX request and then reloading the page. These are two different requests. The POST data is only sent with the first.

There are a number of other options:

- Use [querystring/GET parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) when setting window.location.href
  (e.g. `index.php?lang=EN`)
- Use a hidden post form on the page and [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) that through jQuery
- Set [session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) in PHP when the POST is made